# What is the unit of float parameter in ofFloat() animation method?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Sorry for my bad english.
I have two ObjectAnimations:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewScale, "scaleX", 1.0f, 100.0f).setDuration(1000),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewTranslation, "translationX", 1.0f, 100.0f).setDuration(1000)
```

Both viewScale and viewTranslation have the same size, same parent size. However, the distance viewScale scaled are not equal with the distance viewTranslation moved.
Can someone please explain me the unit of parameter in ofFloat() method. It took me 2 days for find out the solution, but seem like I can't.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the following code? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I set it play together and I expect the distance viewScale has scaled is equal with the distance viewTranslation has moved. But It did't work.

Comment: TranslationX would translate your view (change x position of your view) by specified amount of pixels, in your example it would be 100 pixels. ScaleX would scale that view by X times, meaning that in your example it would be scaled by 100 times. They should not be the same, why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: To be clear, I am drawing diagram: https://imgur.com/a/uEyRE
With each item, I want to animate the averageItem and the currentBar to their values.
So I need the common unit for ScaleX currentBar and translationX averageItem.